# How can I create delays in multithreading for HTTP requests?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using multithreading in python to send HTTP requests, but if I send too many simultanesouly, my request gets blocked.

So I would like to send the requests 5 by 5.
This is what I tried to do, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
for task in tasks:
      thread = Thread(target=send_request,args=(arg1,arg2))
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)

total = len(threads)
    
for x in range(0, total, 5):
    for t in threads[min(total,x):min(total,(x+5))]:
        t.join()
```

Basically, I want all 5 threads of `send_request()` to complete, before I send another 5 request.
What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for threading.Barrier. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

It seems to do exactly what you’re looking for.